# PyMC: multivariate estimation in non-stationary noise

Tags: python, mcmc, pymc

Is there a possibility to use pymc for the following task: the signal is non-linear function of two variables that I want to estimate, the noise is non-stationary, correlating at different moments of time? The distribution of the noise is gaussian with zero mean and covariation function depending on time. The signal is deterministic.

I'm new to pymc and don't know how to construct appropriate likelihood function in this case.

Would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Is the time-varying variance of the noise known, or does it have to be estimated as well?